# More elegant / pythonic way to append to an array, or create it

Tags: python, arrays

For some reason the following code felt a bit cumbersome to me, given all the syntactic sugar I keep finding in Python, so I thought enquire if there's a better way:

```
pictures = list_of_random_pictures()
invalid_pictures = {}
for picture in pictures:
    if picture_invalid(picture):
        if not invalid_pictures.get(picture.album.id):
            invalid_pictures[picture.album.id] = []
        invalid_pictures[picture.album.id].append(picture)
```

So just to clarify, I'm wondering if there's a more readable way to take care of the last 3 lines above. As I'm repeating `invalid_pictures[picture.album.id]` 3 times, it just seems unnecessary if it's at all avoidable.

**EDIT**: Just realized my code above will KeyError, so I've altered it to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, in fact, an object in the standard library to deal exactly with that case: [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

It takes as its argument either a type or function which produces the default value for a missing key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

invalid_pictures = defaultdict(list)
for picture in pictures:
    if picture_invalid(picture):
        invalid_pictures[picture.album.id].append(picture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I do find Joel's answer to be the usual solution, there's an often overlooked feature that is sometimes preferrable. when a default value isn't particularly desired is to use `dict.setdefault()`, when inserting the default is something of an exception (and `collections.defaultdict` is suboptimal.  your code, adapted to use `setdefault()` would be

```
pictures = list_of_random_pictures()
invalid_pictures = {}
for picture in pictures:
    if picture_invalid(picture):
        invalid_pictures.setdefault(picture.album.id, []).append(picture)
```

although this has the downside of creating a lot of (probably unused) lists, so in the particular case of setting the default to a list, it's still often better to use a `defaultdict`, and then copy it to a regular dict to strip off the default value.  This doesn't particularly apply to immutable types, such as `int` or `str`.

For example, [pep-333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) requires that the `environ` variable be a regular `dict`, not a subclass or instance of `collections.Mapping`, but a real, plain ol' dict.  Another case is when you aren't so much as passing through an iterator and applying to a flat mapping; but each key needs special handling, such as when applying defaults to a configuration.